# How can I exclude asterisk in a regex expression

Tags: regex

Noob question:

I want to find all lines that have a single quote anywhere, followed immediately by the word select

'select

followed by any number of spaces

and after the spaces, **not** followed by an asterisk.

I thought [^*]  would be the tail end, but I can't even get that working.

Any help?

Comment: Show us what it should match and what it should NOT match. Give us two examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex.

```
'select\s+[^*\s]
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/oS2aS4/1