# Dialogflow RE2 Regex

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am new here. I wanted to ask a question on using REGEX for an entity in DialogFlow

I wanted the entity to accept all text and spaces except for the symbol *

I have tried to use [A-Za-z0-9 ][^*], but it is not working. Any advice. thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an example of a string you are trying to match against?

Answer (score 0):

In your Regex expression, `[^*]` means "capture any character at the start of the line."  To refer to a literal asterisk rather than matching any character, you need to use `\*`

If you want to match a line of letters or numbers as in the `[A-Za-z0-9]` example you give, but only if that string does not include an asterisk, then this expression should work for you:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

This means "match a whole line of text if it only contains one or more of the characters a-z, A-Z, or 0-9".

If you want to match any character or group of characters in a line except for the asterisk, then you could use something like this:

```
(?!\*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?<!\*)
```

The first part is called a "negative lookahead," and it looks forward to ensure we're not matching the asterisk.  The last part is called a "negative lookbehind," and it looks backwards to make sure we're not matching the asterisk.  The middle part is your "capture group," and confirms that you're matching any letters or numbers in a given string, but excluding the * character.

If this Regex gets input like `*abc`, it will capture `abc`.  If it encounters `abc*`, it will still capture `abc`.  If it encounters `abc*def`, it will capture `abc` and `def` separately in two capture groups, because it will break around the asterisk.

This link explains the concept of [lookarounds in Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  You can also use [this Regex tester](https://regex101.com/) to get started practicing your Regular Expressions with explanations of what each block of characters does.

*EDITED TO ADD* If you're just interested in matching single characters rather than groups of characters, you can use `[A-Za-z0-9]` and match any upper or lowercase letter and any single digit.  You don't need to exclude the `*` character, because the character group is already exclusive.

This is a slight duplicate of the question below, so responses here may also help you.  Hope this helps!

[How can I exclude asterisk in a regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734461/how-can-i-exclude-asterisk-in-a-regex-expression)

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Za-z0-9 ][^*]
```

What you regex will do is match 2 consecutive characters. First, it will look for anything A-Za-z0-9 . Then, it will look at the negated set that includes *, and will match ANY character except *.

You can type your regex into https://regexr.com/ to see a breakdown of how it matches and test some strings.

For example, your regex would match these:

```
Aa
AA
a&
A1
0_
```

But would not match these:

```
A*
a*
1*
```

And WOULD NOT match anything longer than 2 characters. If you really want to match any string with any characters except *, this should work:

```
[^\*]+
```

What that will do is match any number of consecutive characters that are not *. (The + means match 1 or more characters in the set). It is also a good idea to escape * because it is also a reserved character in regex. Even though most regex parsers are smart enough to know that inside a group you probably mean the literal char *, it is still a best practice to escape it. (And by that same token, you would want to use \s instead of the blank space in your original regex.)